# iTunes - How to actually synchronize libraries between 2 Mac with Google Drive

Tags: itunes, music, mp3, playlist, google-apps

I have two macs (Mavericks) plus the latest version of iTunes. 
What I want to do is to mirror any change I do on one library to the other iTunes library using Google Drive (iTunes Library Mac 1 to iTunes Library Mac 2 and vice versa).

I installed Google Drive on both of my Macs. It works pretty well at mirroring changes in .mp3 files names changes I do (i.e. My_Song.mp3 to MY_SONG.mp3), new files I add or files I delete.

But there are two things I can't sync right now. Playlists and files info attributes (i.e. when I switch the soundtrack Genre of one of my soundtrack it doesn't sync with the same soundtrack on my other mac).

I know I can export+import playlist but I don't know how to actually sync using Google Drive. iTunes has a special way of "storing" playlists. What I want is, for example, I create/modify a playlist on my Mac1 and it sync to Mac2 via Google sync. I allready put all my mp3 files in my Google Drive. That doesn't help synching the two iTunes library.

So, how can I make my playlists + any changes I make on my soundtracks (not the mp3 files) sync between my Macs using Google Drive?

Comment: Have you looked into BitTorrent Sync? Be careful though as iTunes, like iPhoto and Aperture, iTunes can be very picky regarding permissions and attribute files.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. No I didn't looked into BitTorrent Sync. I do not really think Google Drive needs an alternative. I tried Dropbox before Google Drive and had the same questions... Maybe I should ask to apple support website.

Answer (score 1):

I find Hazel to be a very useful app for this and many other tasks. It works similarly to Folder Actions, only it has more flexibility and actions, uses less resource, and it actually works. On Mac1, I assigned the Sync action to each of the iTunes folders I want to keep in sync. (I advise against syncing the Applications folder. It requires user interaction.) It only syncs one direction, so it won't start deleting or duplicating items on Mac1.
On Mac2, I assigned the Import into iTunes action to the parent iTunes folder, naming a generic playlist. It detects any new files added to any of the subfolders and adds them to the library.
The only thing is that it will also delete files if you delete them from Mac1, and it doesn't delete them from the library in Mac2. I have a scheduled job for Track Sift to run routinely, anyway, and it cleans up dead tracks, amongst other housekeeping chores.

Comment: Thanks GBinLondon. Hazel seems to fit your needs. I find this application accident prone (to much automation to me + no support at all). I decided to just use a NAS. Update NAS to Mac 1 / Then update NAS to Mac 2.